# innerHTML showes blank in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to take the user input text of an *textarea* [**textBox**] and put it on the *p* [**cParagraph**]
its working on IE but not on Chrome

```
function toggleOverlay(){
  var overLay = document.querySelector("#overlay"),
      modal = document.querySelector("#modal"); 

  if(overLay.style.display !== "block" || modal.style.display !== "block"){
  overLay.style.display = "block";
  modal.style.display = "block";
    }else {
        overLay.style.display = "none";
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function submitMsg() {
  var cHeader = document.querySelector(".cHeader"),
      cParagraph = document.querySelector(".cParagraph"),
      userName = document.querySelector("#userName"),
      textBox = document.querySelector("#textBox");
  cParagraph.innerHTML = textBox.innerHTML;
  cHeader.innerHTML = userName.value;
  toggleOverlay();  
}
document.querySelector("#post").addEventListener("click", toggleOverlay,false);
document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", submitMsg, false);
```

Comment: shouldn't this be textBox.value instead of textBox.innerHTML?

Comment: You want us to guess your HTML?

Comment: My mistake I used the textBox.innerHTML while I should have used the textBox.value for a textarea Thanks [Remigius Stalder]